# How to Enable scroll in PageViewController after disable delay in button highlighted in SWIFT 2.0

Tags: swift, button, scroll

I just have trouble with button highlighted delay in UIPageViewController.
I can solve now by setting property "delaysContentTouches" = false to subview.
But now i can't scroll page anymore. i search forum and found "gestureRecognizers" which might help. but i don't know how to set.
could you help suggest me?

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var pages = [UIViewController]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self

        //declare all pages
        let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("c01")
        let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("c02")
        let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("c03")

        pages.append(page1)
        pages.append(page2)
        pages.append(page3)

        setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
}


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        for view in self.view.subviews {
            if view is UIScrollView {
                (view as? UIScrollView)!.delaysContentTouches = false
            }
        }
    }



    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController) else {
            return nil
        }   
        let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1
        guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
            return pages.last
        }  
        guard pages.count > previousIndex else {
            return nil
        } 
        return pages[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let viewControllerIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController) else {
            return nil
        }        
        let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
        let orderedViewControllersCount = pages.count
        guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
            return pages.first
        } 
        guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
            return nil
        }    
        return pages[nextIndex]
    }    

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, why you want the button delay action? If you want to enable the button only after reaching the maximum number of pages, that is easy.

Comment: What exactly do you want from GestureRecognizer?

Comment: sorry, i am not english native.

my app consists of four pages. each page contains full of buttons in entire view.
i use UIPageViewController to implement swipe between page.

first problem is  when i tap a button. Its highlighted status is delay to appear. this makes the feeling that the button is not responded to tap.

i search and can solve this problem by setting property "delaysContentTouches" in sub view to false.  It makes button highlighted status changes immediately when tap.

but now comes the next problem 
I can't swipe to next page because every touch is considered as tapping

Comment: please post some images showing how the page looks like with buttons. I'm sure there is a way to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it now.

It is not possible for uipageviewcontroller.
i have to move to uiscrollviewcontroller 
then subclass it and override function touchesShouldCancelInContentView for all my UIButton to be true.

now i can tap button without delay and can still hold my finger to scroll.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look around and take the [tour], and read through the [help]. You can also read about [answer].